# To check if a number is n choose r

Tags: combinatorics

Is there an efficient way to find the number n, given a number N (may be as large as 10^18) which is equal to nCr for some n and r ? How do we find the corresponding minimum value of n? for instance

f(20)=6 (20=6C3)
f(21)= 7 (21=7C2)
f(22)= 22 (22=22C1)

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality, assume that $r \leq n/2$. Then $\binom{n}{r}$ is strictly increasing in both $n$ and $r$, so finding the minimum possible value for $n$ is equivalent to finding the maximum possible value for $r$.

If $r \leq n/2$ and $\binom{n}{r} < 10^{18}$, the number of possible values for $r$ is fairly restricted. In particular, $\binom{64}{32} \approx 1.8 \times 10^{18}$ is the smallest binomial coefficient with $r \geq 32$, so we can restrict our attention to $r \leq 31$.

Moreover, if $r \geq 20$, there are a relatively small number of $n$ to check. Note that $\binom{76}{20} \approx 1.09 \times 10^{18}$. So to discover whether there is a solution to $\binom{n}{r}=N$ with $r \geq 20$, we need only compute the relatively small number of values of $\binom{n}{r}$ with $2r \leq n \leq 75$, and check to see whether any of those values are equal to $N$.

Now, fix $r \leq 19$. The equation $\binom{n}{r}=N$ is equivalent to
$$
\prod_{k=0}^{r-1} (n-k) = r!N \, ,
$$
positive integer solutions to which must satisfy $n - r + 1 < \sqrt[r]{r!N} < n$, leaving only about $r$ possible values of $n$ to check. Since $r \leq 19$, $r! < 10^{18}$, so this only involves arithmetic with numbers of size at most $10^{36}$ — well within reach of a modern computer.

Moreover, there are only $19$ possible values of $r$ to worry about. So in total, we only have about $19^2/2 \approx 180$ candidate pairs of $n$ and $r$ to check, which again is entirely tractable.